# Tomcat 8 IP to domai name

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, server, tomcat8

I'm using tomcat 8 on Windows server 2016. I have configured SSL and now I want to redirect users from IP to domain name. So for example if you enter Domain Name Server: 31.13.69.228 you will be redirected to facebook.com. I have tried different things like, adding in server.xml:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

and created a file under /conf/Catalina/localhost rewrite.config with following entry

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

where 111.111.111.111 represents my ip and sub.domain.com represents a domain to which i want to redirect user.

Comment: redirect != rewrite. What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: yes, i just want to set that users can not open page by IP address but just with domain name. so if user enters IP address don't show him page doesn't exist but automatically go to domain name, like i give an example with facebook. 31.13.69.228 -> facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat committer here...

This is pure non-sense. The [*Domain Name System (DNS)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) has been developed for humans **not** to memorize [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address). There is no need to tell the user the IP address. In fact, you are creating issues like IP address changes, DNS [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)), etc. No serious server/application operates on pure IP addresses.

Comment: I’m not telling users ip address, they are redirected from main page to this dashboard with link, but i just need to do that redirect for some other reasons.

Comment: @elvirt which are?

Comment: He's trying to prevent users from using an IP address, or actually to convert it to a domain name if they happened to use an IP address.  I came here to find out the opposite, we just had a DDOS attack that took out our DNS entries and left us stranded, I'd like to be able to tell our customers "Well, just use our IP address" but something is rewriting our IP address to a name (which then fails to resolve).